Set nimbus as the default look and feel for all java applications that run on your computer
I run this java code
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Dialog1{
        public static void main(String[] args){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Welcome to Java");
        }
}

I get this

Then I say I want to set nimbus as the default look and feel for all java applications that run on my computer. So I write this code on a text editor and save the file as swing.properties
swing.defaultlaf=javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel

I copy that file on C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\lib like this

When I run the code of class Dialog1 above I still get the same look and feel

I mean I thought I should get a nimbus look and feel, cause I did everything right or at least I think so. I wonder where I was wrong, someone please help. I use java version "17.0.10"

This seems like a good thing to do, but isn't. You will forget in time or someone else will wonder why on earth that is happening. Fortunately it wouldn't be too easy to do ;)

@g00se do you know what I must do, to set nimbus as the default look and feel for all my java applications please give me an answer, even if it's not easy

Provide a batch file called java.bat that invokes something like java -Dswing.defaultlaf=javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel %* Make sure the directory that contains that batch file is prepended to PATH Advisable? Absolutely not ;)

Some sites say lib or bin but it only worked for me with conf folder. Copy your new settings file to {jdk-17-home}\conf\swing.properties.
